# Evaluating if an attribute value is parseable to a xs:int

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xquery-3.0

**Background:**

I am trying to perform a query (using XQuery 3.0) on an attribute value (`attrname`) that might be either an `xs:string` or an `xs:int`, lets call it `$a`.

If `$a` is able to be parsed to an `xs:int` then I want to compare it against an `xs:int` variable `$v` (`<`, `<=`, `=`, etc.).
Otherwise, if it is an `xs:string` I want to perform a different comparison.

**XML Example**

```
<root>
  <element attrname="1">this is an xs:int</element>
  <element attrname="A">this is an xs:string</element>
</root>
```

**Pseudo-code**

```
IF $a IS xs:int THEN
  DO SOMETHING
ELSE IF $a IS xs:string THEN
  DO SOMETHING ELSE
```

**My Issue:**

I am not able to find a proper way of evaluating if `$a` is an `xs:int` before performing any operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `if ($a castable as xs:int) then expression1 else expression2`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as a charm. I feel kinda stupid now as I found it on the documentation.